# How to add "move to" commands to an Adobe Illustrator path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

So when you export an Adobe Illustrator file to SVG format, paths are encoded using the [SVG path syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html).

If you look at the `<path data>` element, it's possible to have `moveto` commands embedded into [a path](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData).

In other words, you draw a few lines in the path, pick up the pen and move it somewhere else, and continue the same path.

I have been trying to figure out how to do this in Illustrator to no avail.  You can add on to an existing path but it seems you can only do this by extending the path from one of the endpoints.  I don't want to do this: I want to continue the path from somewhere else.

You can get something sort of like this by grouping two disjoint paths.  However when Illustrator does the svg export it just creates two `<path>` tags and puts them inside a `<g>` tag which is not what I want.  If I manually edit an svg file with a text editor, adding "move to" commands, and I import them, it looks like maybe what Illustrator is doing is creating a group, but I can't tell because I don't know how to select and object and figure out if it is a group or not.

Answer (score 4):

**Summary:** `Object > Compound Path > Make`

How to find this answer:

1. Create an SVG file that has a path using move-to commands:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
        viewBox="-25 -25 100 100">
     <path d="M0,0 L50,0 M50,50 L0,50" stroke="black" />
   </svg>
   ```
2. Open this file in Illustrator. Note that there is a single element named `<Compound Path>` in the Layers palette.
3. Choose command `Object > Compound Path > Release`. Now there are two paths selected.
4. Choose command `Object > Compound Path > Make`.
5. Save as SVG file (I've manually wrapped the output for easier viewing here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="612px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792"
     enable-background="new 0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
  <path stroke="#000000" d="M128,218h306 M434,524H128"/>
</svg>
```

6. Cheer as you see a single `<path>` with absolute **M**ove commands in it!

Answer (score 0):

As documented, at the WYSIWYG level, there is no functionality in AI that will implement what you're looking for, but apparently there is a way! See Phrogz comment below. Otherwise, it becomes a matter for scripting or hand tweaking (or whipping up some fancy grep!).

Comment: I'd downvote, but I've no rep here for that. See my answer: Compound Paths in Illustrator export to SVG as a single path with `move-to` commands jumping between each.

Comment: That's good to know, because it's entirely undocumented. I'll revise the answer to refer to your comment.